# selection of nlm starting values problem

Tags: r, error-handling, for-loop, nlm

Need to estimate two parameters using the nlm function;

```
fit<-nlm(hood2par,c(x01[i],x02[j]),iterlim=300, catch=x[,c(3,4,5)],sp=.5)
```

where `hood2par` is a modified logistic

The convergence of nlm depends on the starting values ​​of these parameters. To find such initial values I ​​automatically generate two  vectors of starting  values

```
x01 = seq(-10,-20,-0.1)
x02 = seq(0.1,0.9,0.01)
```

next I  create a routine included in a double for() to find the values ​​that lead to the convergence of the function:

```
for (i in 1:length(x01)) { for (j in 1:length(x02)) {

fit <- NULL
try(fit <- nlm(hood2par, c(x01[i],x02[j]), iterlim = 300, catch = x[,c(3,4,5)],
               sp = .5), 
    silent = TRUE)
stopifnot(is.null(fit))}}
```

The problem I have is that when I include the previous routine in a function:

```
FFF <- function(x01, x02, catch){
    for (i in 1:length(x01)) { 
        for (j in 1:length(x02)) {
            fit <- NULL
            try(fit <- nlm(hood2par, c(x01[i], x02[j]), iterlim = 300,
                           catch = x[,c(3,4,5)], sp = .5), 
               silent = TRUE) # does not stop in the case of err
            stopifnot(is.null(fit))
        }
     }  
return(fit)
}
```

I can´t get the 'fit' values from FFF():

```
> fit.fff<-FFF(x01,x02,catch)
#Error: is.null(fit) is not TRUE 

>fit.fff
fit.fff
Error: object 'fit.fff' not found
```

---

I used `stopifnot(is.null(fit))` to stop the loops when fit is not NULL (as fit is defined as a NULL object before try(...)). Regarding the try code you have shared, I just need this;

```
res <- try(some_expression)
if(inherits(res, "try-error"))
{
  #some code to keep loops running
} else
{
  #stop the loops and gather "res" 
}
```

I tried to include the `break` function in the second argument of the condictional, but it doesn´t run in my R version...Any idea??

Comment: It makes it *so* much easier to read if you space out and indent your code!!

Comment: thank you Gavin for your comment

Comment: @Juan: Saying "it doesn't run" isn't specific enough to be useful.  Does it throw an error?  If so, which error?  Or does it just give different behaviour than expected?  More details please!

Comment: @Juan: Also, problems are easier to solve when the code is reproducible, which yours isn't (since `hood2par` isn't provided).

Answer (score 4):

When you call `FFF`, inside the try block if `nlm` successfully completes, then `fit` is assigned, and the `stopifnot` condition is activated, throwing an error.

Wildly guessing, did you mean

```
stopifnot(!is.null(fit))
```

---

For future reference, a standard chunk of code for use with `try` is

```
res <- try(some_expression)
if(inherits(res, "try-error"))
{
  #some error handling code
} else
{
  #normal execution
}
```